# Sitecore Forms rendering content from Master database not from web database. How to configure it to get published content?

Tags: sitecore-forms

Sitecore Forms rendering renders content from `Master` database not from `Web` database. How to configure it to render published content?

Comment: try to see in https://youhostname/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx, what database is set?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your `sitecore.config` or `SiteDefinition.Config` or any custom config that what database is set for your site. It should be web.

And then try to run showconfig page by going to `https://hostname/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and search for your website and check, the database should be set web here.

Comment: Yes..the database context set to master db. Thank you.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this works for you, so in future anyone else will face the same issue, they can also see this.

Answer (score 0):

As Meenu suggested you can check your `sitecore.config` or `siteDefinition.Config` what database is set there

```
<site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            name="yourSite"
            hostName="local.yourSite.com"
            targetHostName="local.yourSite.com"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/Your Site"
            startItem="/Your Site"
            database="master"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="false"
            htmlCacheSize="10MB"
            registryCacheSize="0"
            viewStateCacheSize="0"
            xslCacheSize="5MB"
            filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false"
            enableCustomErrors="false"
            dictionaryDomain="{000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000}"/>
```

As shown in above configuration if database is set to `master` then content will render from `master` database, and if database is set to `web` in that you have to published your content related to forms data then content will render from `web` database.

Hope this helps you.